# Firefox Aurora 13 and Flash Plugin problem

Tags: 11.10, firefox, flash

I have a problem when using Aurora 13
I can't install flash plugin player
whenever I tried to install it, it said that my Aurora Firefox will be removed
anyone can help

Comment: You are using alpha quality software. This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: Update it now. I have updated it. Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just install the Flash-Aid plugin. It will choose the flash version for your browser version. It worked for me even when adobe said that they will not support flash for FireFox anymore. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flash-aid/

Comment: please do not post the identical answer you have previously made.  If you think this is the same solution, please flag for this to marked as a duplicate.  Thanks.